# Changing text after getDay method

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css

I am making an application (with HTML, CSS, and Javascript) that allows users to view the daily specials for bars in their area.

My question: How should I change the specials by using the `getDay()` method?

My problem: I need to be able to update the specials for each bar whenever I want. Therefore, the app will have to retrieve the information from my server (so I don't have to update the app for each special change).

My idea: Is it easiest to make a MySQL table for every bar and edit the tables when the specials change? Or is there another way to do this?

Example:
The home page of the app is "Today's Specials". I will use `getDay()` method to figure out what day of the week it is. I am thinking that after I get the day (if it is Friday) I can pull from the "Friday" row of the "Corner Bar" table and fill the Corner Bar text box with the items that are in that row.

When I need to change the "Friday" specials at the "Corner Bar" I will just edit the Friday row in the table. Would this be the best way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Can you post some code for us to see?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to have two tables?  One as a bar catalog (barID, barname, someinfo) and a second table with the specials (ID, barID, dayOfWeek, Specials) And you could simply query to whatever day of the week you want with a simple join.